# android:set gray scale filter to imageView

Tags: android, svg, imageview, android-image, androidsvg

i use this [library](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) to show svg image on imageView , i want to show locked and unlocked mode with this imageView, when state is locked show imageView in grayscale color filter. 
something like this code on css :

`-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
opacity: 0.5;`

how can i do this ? can anybody help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 78):

You should be able to make the image greyscale and faded using the following:

```
public static void  setLocked(ImageView v)
{
    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0);  //0 means grayscale
    ColorMatrixColorFilter cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    v.setColorFilter(cf);
    v.setImageAlpha(128);   // 128 = 0.5
}
```

And reset it using:

```
public static void  setUnlocked(ImageView v)
{
    v.setColorFilter(null);
    v.setImageAlpha(255);
}
```

Comment: Ah.  I feared that might be the case.  You could use the replace-color feature of svg-android (`getSVGFromInputStream(is, searchColor, replaceColor)`), or you may just have to render the SVG to a Bitmap and set the ImageView to use that.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau you can use `clearColorFilter()` method which internally does the same thing which you have stated in soloution

Comment: @AkshayMukadam, yes 'clearColorFilter()' works well, but it doesn't give back the exact old color what was before the filter. Thanks.

Comment: @Kotdroid then what is the alternate way can you share .Please

Comment: @AkshayMukadam , I don't have any alternative yet. But I used Paul's way. And it is working well.